# Equivalent of 'curl --cookie-jar' for Python's requests library

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I would like to know how to do the equivalent of this:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://example.com/some/path" ... --cookie-jar "/Path/On/My/Computer"
```

Using Python's requests library. I tried something like this:

```
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
import requests

jar = CookieJar()  # <-- the path should surely be set somehow, but unsure how

session = requests.session()
response = session.post("https://example.com/some/path", cookies=jar, ...)
```

Although I can't make it work, I keep getting a 403. It works when I try it with Insomnia (https://insomnia.rest/), so the credentials I'm sending are ok, but the cookie jar part is unclear to me. Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar` instead? See [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) for an example.